# modularizing htmls and javascripts in a web page

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using Django, Backbone, requirejs but the question could apply to other stacks of libraries.

I like the concept of `subtemplate` in html.
In django, we can `{% include other.html %}` from a html.
(edit: these are subtemplates that gets rendered in server-side)

I used to put javascript code in the subtemplates so that I can clearly see the html and javascript put together.

My typical html looks like

```
<div id="my-id">
 ...
</div>

<script>
    require(['my_view'], function(MyView) {
    new MyView({el: 'my-id'});
    });
</script>
```

Now, the problem is it creates a tons of files, and it makes webpage slow.

requirejs can combine several javascripts files but not the subtemplate html files.

My question is how should I structure my files (html/js files) so that I can still see the html/js in one place (close places) and strip down the number of files users have to download?

Answer (score 0):

You can require you html files by [text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) for reqirejs.

Also optimizer will inline it in single file when you will build your app.

Comment: I should have been more clear, the subtemplates I mentioned is django-template not client-template..